# How to do rolling sum over columns in R?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

roll_sum and many other methods (e.g. https://vandomed.github.io/moving_averages.html) are for summing over rows only. I have a large matrix that I don't have enough memory to transpose it. Is there a way I can do roll_sum over columns directly?

For example:

```
library(roll)

A=matrix(rnorm(10000),100)
roll_sum(A,3)
```

But I want to do this across columns.

---

To follow up, all of the methods so far are implemented without using multi-core processing. Can anyone offer a solution with this feature?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) approach.

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("
NumericMatrix rcpp_column_roll(const NumericMatrix mat, const int n) {

  const int ncol = mat.ncol();
  const int nrow = mat.nrow();
  NumericMatrix out(nrow, ncol);
  std::fill( out.begin(), out.end(), NumericVector::get_na() ) ;

  
  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    NumericVector window(n);
    double roll = 0;
    int oldest_ind = 0;
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++) {
      double mat_ij = mat(i, j); 
      window(j) = mat_ij;
      roll += mat_ij;
    }
    
    out(i, n - 1) = roll;

    for (int j = n; j < ncol; j ++) {
      double mat_ij = mat(i, j); 
      
      roll += mat_ij;
      roll -= window(oldest_ind);
      
      out(i, j) = roll;
      
      window(oldest_ind) = mat_ij;
      
      if (oldest_ind == n-1) oldest_ind = 0; else oldest_ind++;
    }
  }
  return(out);
}
")
```

This is about 10x more memory efficient than transposing the result of `apply(A, 1L, roll::roll_sum, 3L)` and about 50x faster for the sample dataset.

```r
bench::mark(rcpp_column_roll(A, 3),
            t(apply(A, 1, roll::roll_sum, 3)))

## # A tibble: 2 x 13
##   expression                             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>                        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 rcpp_column_roll(A, 3)             134.4us  139.7us     6641.    80.7KB
## 2 t(apply(A, 1, roll::roll_sum, 3))   7.62ms   8.91ms      101.     773KB

## With an 80 MB dataset (`rnorm(1E7)`):

##   expression                          min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>                        <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 rcpp_column_roll(A, 3)            226ms  229ms      4.17    76.3MB
## 2 t(apply(A, 1, roll::roll_sum, 3)) 740ms  740ms      1.35   498.5MB

## 800 MB dataset (`rnorm(1E8)`):

## # A tibble: 2 x 13
##   expression                          min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>                        <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 rcpp_column_roll(A, 3)            3.49s  3.49s     0.286  762.94MB
## 2 t(apply(A, 1, roll::roll_sum, 3)) 9.62s  9.62s     0.104    4.84GB
```

The memory savings seem to be stabilizing at about a 5-fold reduction and is more-or-less the allocation of the result matrix itself.

Alternatively, we can approach it more R-like and use an R loop to make a manual `apply` that does not need to be transposed.

```r
out = matrix(NA_real_, nrow(A), ncol(A))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(A))) {
  out[i, ] = roll::roll_sum(A[i, ], 3L)
}
```

Is is moderately better than transposing the regular `apply`. @Moody_Mudskipper has the fastest approach although [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) is the most memory efficient.

```r
##rnorm(1e8); ncols = 1000;
# A tibble: 6 x 13
  expression               min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr
  <bch:expr>             <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int>
1 rcpp_column_roll(A, 3) 3.32s  3.32s     0.301  762.94MB    0         1
2 for_loop               6.12s  6.12s     0.163    2.98GB    0.327     1
3 dww_sappy                 7s     7s     0.143    4.86GB    0.572     1
4 matStat_Moody          1.81s  1.81s     0.552    2.24GB    0.552     1
5 roll_sum_Ronak         8.34s  8.34s     0.120    4.84GB    0.360     1
6 froll_Oliver           7.75s  7.75s     0.129    4.86GB    0.516     1
```

Note if you are really short on RAM, you can change the Rcpp function to modify the input directly, meaning you do not  have to allocate another matrix. Otherwise you may be better off implementing Moody's clever solution in Rcpp as it would be faster and only need to allocate the out matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting benchmarks! (and the great solution)

Comment: Thanks. This is a very good answer but do you think it's also possible to use multi-core in doing this?

Comment: I looked into it.  Multi-core didn't really help me. It is likely memory preventing performance. That is, it takes resources to split up the dataset and make everything available to each core. I would expect copies of the matrix need to be made for each process since a matrix is stored in memory in a contiguous manner meaning we can't take the first row of data without first having access to the main matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Since a rolling sum can be seen as a subtraction of cumsums we can use the package *{MatrixStats}* which does these cumsums fast.

```r
A <- matrix(1:25,5)
A
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
#> [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
#> [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
#> [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
#> [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

What you can't do because of costly transpose :

```
library(roll)
t(roll_sum(t(A),3))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]   NA   NA   18   33   48
#> [2,]   NA   NA   21   36   51
#> [3,]   NA   NA   24   39   54
#> [4,]   NA   NA   27   42   57
#> [5,]   NA   NA   30   45   60
```

with *{MatrixStats}*

```
library(matrixStats)
#> Warning: le package 'matrixStats' a été compilé avec la version R 4.0.3
row_roll_sum <- function(x, width) {
out <- rowCumsums(x)
out[,seq(width+1,ncol(out))] <- out[,seq(width+1,ncol(out))] -  out[,seq(ncol(out)-width)]
out[,seq(width-1)] <- NA
out
}
row_roll_sum(A, 3)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]   NA   NA   18   33   48
#> [2,]   NA   NA   21   36   51
#> [3,]   NA   NA   24   39   54
#> [4,]   NA   NA   27   42   57
#> [5,]   NA   NA   30   45   60
```

Answer (score 3):

Using base R matrix indexing we can do

```
n = 3
sapply(seq_len(NCOL(A)-n+1), function(j) rowSums(A[, j:(j+n-1)]))
```

No transpose required, and `rowSums` should be pretty optimized for speed.

Answer (score 3):

## Rolling Sums by Columns or Rows

### `Rcpp` function for roll sums by column or row

Since it’s pretty useful to be able to do this by row or column, I
included the `margin` argument with the same usage seen in `base::apply`
(i.e. 1=rows, 2=columns).

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix matrix_rollsum(SEXP x, int n, int margin) {
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix y(x);
  int NR = y.nrow();
  int NC = y.ncol();
  NumericMatrix result(NR,NC);
  std::fill( result.begin(), result.end(), NumericVector::get_na() ) ;

  if(margin==1){
    for(int i = 0; i < NR; ++i){
      NumericVector tmpvec = y(i,_);
      for(int j = 0; j < NC-n+1;++j){
        double s=0.0;
        for(int q=j; q<j+n;q++){
          s+=tmpvec[q];
        }
        result(i,j+n-1) = s;
        s = 0.0;
      }}}

  if(margin==2){

    for(int i = 0; i < NC; ++i){
      NumericVector tmpvec = y(i,_);
      for(int j = 0; j < NR-n+1;++j){
        double s=0.0;
        for(int q=j; q<j+n;q++){
          s+=tmpvec[q];
        }
        result(j+n-1,i) = s;
        s = 0.0;
      }}}

  return result;
}
```

### Benchmarks

```r
mat_lg <- matrix(runif(1e6,1,1000),1e3,1e3)
res1 <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  matrix_rollsum = matrix_rollsum(mat_lg, 3,1),
  rcpp_colum_roll = rcpp_column_roll(mat_lg,3), 
  apply_rollsum = apply_rollsum(mat_lg,3),
  for_loop = for_loop(mat_lg,3),
  row_roll_sum = row_roll_sum(mat_lg,width = 3),
  times = 1000
)

knitr::kable(summary(res1))
```

| expr | min | lq | mean | median | uq | max | neval | cld |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| matrix_rollsum | 9.128677 | 10.38814 | 15.78466 | 13.43251 | 17.54006 | 71.10719 | 1000 | a |
| rcpp_colum_roll | 23.195918 | 26.54276 | 33.65227 | 30.43353 | 38.11125 | 113.20687 | 1000 | b |
| apply_rollsum | 58.027111 | 72.66437 | 87.12061 | 80.50741 | 94.53146 | 255.69353 | 1000 | c |
| for_loop | 56.408078 | 71.78122 | 85.21565 | 79.10471 | 89.47916 | 269.55304 | 1000 | c |
| row_roll_sum | 8.309067 | 10.40819 | 15.62686 | 12.93160 | 17.21942 | 81.76514 | 1000 | a |

### Benchmarks with memory allocation

```r
res2 <- bench::mark(
  matrix_rollsum = matrix_rollsum(mat_lg, 3,1),
  rcpp_colum_roll = rcpp_column_roll(mat_lg,3), 
  apply_rollsum = apply_rollsum(mat_lg,3),
  for_loop = for_loop(mat_lg,3),
  row_roll_sum = row_roll_sum(mat_lg,width = 3),
  iterations = 1000
)

summary(res2)[,1:9]
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  expression           min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
  <bch:expr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
1 matrix_rollsum    9.11ms   11.1ms      79.7   15.31MB    29.0 
2 rcpp_colum_roll   23.2ms   28.6ms      32.2    7.63MB     3.74
3 apply_rollsum    53.94ms   67.1ms      13.7   52.18MB   188.  
4 for_loop         55.18ms     69ms      13.2   33.13MB    17.8 
5 row_roll_sum      8.28ms   10.5ms      78.3   22.87MB    51.5
```

### Benchmark Plots

```r
p1 <- ggplot2::autoplot(res1)
p2 <- ggplot2::autoplot(res2)

library(patchwork)
p1/p2
```

[image]

---

## Edit

Cole brought up a great point. Why copy a large matrix? Wouldn't working on the original object utilize less memory? So I rewrote the `Rcpp` function to use the original object.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix test(NumericMatrix x, int n, int margin) {

  Rcpp::NumericMatrix result(x.nrow(),x.ncol());
  std::fill( result.begin(), result.end(), NumericVector::get_na() ) ;
  double s=0.0;

  if(margin==1){
    for(int i = 0; i < x.nrow(); ++i){
      for(int j = 0; j < x.ncol()-n+1;++j){
        for(int q=j; q<j+n;q++){
          s+=x(i,q);
        }
        result(i,j+n-1) = s;
        s = 0.0;
      }}}

  if(margin==2){

    for(int i = 0; i < x.ncol(); ++i){
      for(int j = 0; j < x.nrow()-n+1;++j){
        for(int q=j; q<j+n;q++){
          s+=x(i,q);
        }
        result(j+n-1,i) = s;
        s = 0.0;
      }}}

  return result;
}
```

### Benchmarks

As Cole suspected, the new function allocated half the memory as the original, yet it was suprisingly 3x slower.

| expr | min | lq | mean | median | uq | max | neval | cld |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| matrix_rollsum | 9.317332 | 10.84904 | 15.47414 | 13.75330 | 16.36336 | 101.6147 | 1000 | a |
| test | 34.498511 | 40.08057 | 47.49839 | 43.26564 | 48.34093 | 211.3246 | 1000 | b |

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
  <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
1 matrix_rollsum   9.15ms   10.1ms      93.7   15.31MB    33.4 
2 test             34.1ms   35.4ms      27.5    7.63MB     3.93
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I feel like you are creating a copy of the input matrix based on memory usage. Why not loop directly on the input matrix as ```NumericMatrix```?

Comment: That's a great thought. I always get nervous directly working on the input data whenever I'm doing something C++ related, but I would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Oh, I'm more of an R guy so if that is shunned in C++ then please ignore. But... I think it makes sense. You are not copying the ```int``` cars before using... Why copy the large matrix? And the good news is that it's hard to "accidentally" assign new values on the input data because you'd have to purposefully put it on the LHS of assignment.

Comment: I'm waaaaaaaay more comfortable in R than C++, and it's not a rational fear. I'm trying right now to only use the input matrix.

Comment: Interesting findings. Out of curiosity, why did you change the approach of the temporary vector?

Comment: Since my goal was to reference the original data rather than copy it, I was trying to remain consistent throughout the rest of the function. Have you gone through  `vignette('Rcpp-FAQ',package = 'Rcpp')`?

Comment: Just reviewed... I think you are still safe copying your original function. The ```NumericVector tmp``` 1) creates a new allocation so changing it would not affect the original object in this case and 2) even if there were a link to ```tmp``` and ```x```, you never reassign to `tmp`.

Comment: Hi @DeweyBrooke can you create a solution using multiple cores?

Comment: @monotonic I’ve done it before, but I’m not an expert on doing it correctly. You need OpenMP.

Comment: Thanks. Can RcppParallel do this too? @DeweyBrooke

Comment: Maybe. I’d be cautious going down that road though, because it is incredibly easy to make an “unstable” function.

Comment: First attempt at it made it significantly slower. I think your best bet would be either RcppArmadillo or using GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can try using `apply` on matrix row-wise :

```
apply(A, 1, zoo::rollsumr, 3, fill = NA)
#Or
#apply(A, 1, roll::roll_sum, 3)
```

However, note that this will give you output in column-order format. For example,

```
A <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 5)
apply(A, 1, zoo::rollsumr, 3, fill = NA)

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA
#[3,]    9   12
#[4,]   15   18
#[5,]   21   24
```

Comment: You are `apply`ing with `MARGIN = 1`, the question is about `MARGIN = 2`.

Comment: I was confused by the question as well but if you take this example `A=matrix(1:10,ncol = 2)` and apply `roll_sum(A,3)` it gives rolling sum column-wise and I guess OP wants opposite of `roll_sum(A,3)`( without transposing) which is rowwise?

Comment: I don't have package roll installed so if that's the case do not consider my comment, I was referring to the question as asked, not to the actual code results.

Comment: Hi it seems that your method also requires transposing the matrix (after rolling sum) which is equality expensive as transposing it before the sum. @RonakShah

Comment: Why do you need to transpose it? You can keep the matrix as it is `apply(A, 1, roll::roll_sum, 3)` @monotonic

Comment: I need to use is for a data frame and there are other operations that I need e.g. matching ID. So keeping the shape of A as its original will be desirable for me.

Comment: Hmm..I am not sure then. As far as I understand nothing changes in terms of your output. Whatever operations previously you were doing rowwise would now be performed columnwise.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the provided answers are equally good here. There seems to be a bit of confusion in the question whether you are looking for a rolling sum over the columns or rows, or whether your output should be transposed by design. If you are looking for the latter I'd suggest looking through Cole's answer and inverting the dimensions and indices of the output matrix.

That say, if what you're looking for is column wise operations and output, you could simply use the `froll*` functions from the `data.table` package, which are designed for speed and memory efficiency.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1e8), ncol = 10))
frollsum = frollsum(mat, 3)
```

I believe the `roll` library has somewhat similar performance however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `embed` for rolling sum

```
out <- NA * A
out[, -(1:2)] <- t(sapply(1:nrow(A), function(k) rowSums(embed(A[k, ], 3))))
```

or

```
out <- NA * A
u <- embed(t(A), 3)
out[, -(1:2)] <- sapply(rev(split(1:ncol(u), ceiling(seq(ncol(u)) / nrow(A)))), function(k) colSums(u[, k]))
```